# Node on same network cannot be reached via ping intermittantly, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: networking

I'm connected via wire to a switch, which is connected to a router, which is connected to another server S. Normally, I can ping S, but now I get the following error:

```
$ ping 196.168.2.106
PING 196.168.2.106 (196.168.2.106) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 173.167.59.141 icmp_seq=4 Destination Net Unreachable
From 173.167.59.141 icmp_seq=19 Destination Net Unreachable
From 173.167.59.141 icmp_seq=26 Destination Net Unreachable
```

My coworker, who is connected to the same switch can ping S, and I can ping my coworker's machine and access the internet. I can also ping another coworker's machine that is connected to a different switch. This error has happened once every few weeks, and I can't figure out why. What might be the problem, and how can I diagnose it?

Here is my /etc/resolv.conf:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.2.1
```

Here is my routing table:

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         router.asus.com 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: It's hard to be sure without you providing addresses but I would guess it's because 196.168.2.106 is a typo.

Comment: Oops, yes, it is a typo. You're right.

Answer (score 1):

Has the server got a static IP address? - specifically double check the netmask on server and router.

Double check the netmasks are the same as a 192.168.0.0 is typically a /24 (255.255.255.0) network where as in your routing you have it as a /16 (255.255.0.0) not an ideal subnet mask to have - obviously depending on your setup but I'm guessing you don't have many devices.

Comment: Yes, the server has a static ip address. Netmask configurations, and the output of `route` are identical on my coworkers' machines (one doesn't have the link local route, but another does -- both of them can ping the server).

Comment: can your server ping them?

Comment: to confirm your server, router and workstations all have the subnet mask /16 (255.255.0.0)?

Comment: @richardb's comment was correct, it was just a typo that I unfortunately repeated multiple times for different ip addresses, but not when pinging my coworker's machines.

Comment: As in issue resolved due to typo?

Comment: Yes, that was the resolution.

Comment: Can you add the answer and accept it yourself then? This question is still listed when people filter for "Unanswered".

Answer (score 0):

You can use tcpdump to help diagnose the problem.  Use it as follows:

```
tcpdump -i <INTERFACE> icmp and host <IPADDR>
```

For example:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 icmp and host 196.168.2.106
```

(Note: the syntax for tcpdump can vary between distributions.  This works for CentOS.)

For each server the host (IP address) needs to be set to the opposite server.

Check to see that the packet:

1. Leaves your server (tcpdump on your system)
2. Reaches the target server (tcdump on the other system)
3. The reply leaves the target server (tcpdump on the other system)
4. The reply reaches your server (tcpdump on your system)

That will help identify where it is failing.

If you have access to the router and `tcpdump` is available there that would help a lot as well.